# Why won't my male leopard gecko show interest in my female leopard gecko?

Tags: breeding, leopard-geckos, geckos

I've had my leopard geckos housed together for a couple weeks now and I have not seen or heard any tail wagging. They don't attack each other and the female pays no mind to him. They even sleep in the same hide together except they don't mate. I've been a leopard gecko owner for more than 4 years and it's always been a dream to breed them. Please help me.

Comment: Sanity check: Have you tried websesrching "leopard gecko breeding"  and following the advice in those articles?

Comment: Did u ever find out? I'm struggling with the same problem